# How can one turn off Subtotals for good?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, pivot-table, powerpivot, subtotal

The most annoying thing I've encountered when working with pivots in Excel is the automatic addition of subtotals. The reason for this is I have a huge database and have to constantly turn off subtotals every time I add a new field row. I've spent so much time because I would wait for it to refresh, remove subtotals, then wait for another refresh.

Is there a way to permanently turn off subtotals in Excel pivot?

Note: I use PowerPivot for my pivot tables.

Comment: This would be a good question for [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/). That site deals more with using applications like Excel than with programming, which is StackOverflow's aim.

Comment: I agree with both the frustration and the suggestion that this be moved to SuperUser